# SharePoint 2007 Search Crawl Logs Error

Tags: search, error

I am getting a couple of errors in the Search Administration Crawl Logs. These errors are just coming for only one list within SharePoint. It has about 6000 .xlsm documents but views have been configured so that it meets Microsoft Recommended Practices. The error is as follows
"**Error in the Site Data Web Service. (The item was deleted because it was either not found or the crawler was denied access to it.)**"

PS

The Default Content Access Account has full read permissions on the Web application the list resides in. Also it has the required permissions that were the pre-requisites. The main thing is the errors are not consistent as in if a document is shown to be not crawled today tomorrow it is being crawled and also there are no checked out documents.But the number of errors are pretty much consistent i.e about 150-160 crawl errors. I also checked the ULS logs but it didn't show anything. Need some help here.

Comment: When you say that the crawl accoutn has Full Read permissions - do you mean that it has specific permissions on the site collection itself or that the Web Application Policy is granting it permissions?

Comment: Can you log onto a machine with the Crawl Account and view the list to be sure you have the right permissions?  About the only other thing I have seen that gives inconsistent errors like you mention are when the crawl times out.  Do your times overlap at all such that one crawl is still in process when the next starts?

Answer (score 1):

The web application policy is granting it full read permissions.

Comment: Well. I tried logging on to the Index server using the default content access account but it didn't allow me to login with a message "unauthorized for login". Which I am assuming sounds right. But I could login to SharePoint using the Default Content Access Account and I could see all the items within the list as it has read permissions